# Convert directly from NSTimeInterval to NSDateComponents to NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdatecomponents, nstimeinterval

I've got several `NSTimeInterval`s derived from previous calculations on various `NSDate`s. Now I want to display these intervals to the user in `days:hours:minutes:seconds` format.

Earlier in my app, I use this code to display the information in a slightly different context:

```
-(void)updateDurationLabel
{
    //Which calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //Gets the componentized interval from the most recent time an activity was tapped until now

    NSDateComponents *components= [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:self.startTime toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSInteger days = [components day];
    NSInteger hours = [components hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
    NSInteger seconds =[components second];

    // Converts the components to a string and displays it in the duration label, updated via the timer

    cellLabelTempText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i:%02i",days,hours,minutes,seconds];
    self.durationOrSleepLabel.text = cellLabelTempText;
}
```

However, in the current case, I would like for the desired `NSString` to be produced using various already-obtained `NSTimeInterval`s for use in several different labels, which are created on the fly.

**Question:**

*Is there some way to get directly to an `NSString` from an existing `NSTimeInterval`, i.e., without going through the `fromDate/toDate` rigamarole?*

Thanks!

**Update:**

Pursuant to @Rich's answer below, I added this method, which skirted the math:

```
-(void) focusItemDurationCalculator
{
    NSInteger days = ((NSInteger) focusItemDuration) / (60 * 60 * 24);
    NSInteger hours = (((NSInteger) focusItemDuration) / (60 * 60)) - (days * 24);
    NSInteger minutes = (((NSInteger) focusItemDuration) / 60) - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
    NSInteger seconds = ((NSInteger) round(focusItemDuration)) % 60;

    actualDurationFocusItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i:%02i",days,hours,minutes,seconds];
}
```

Works great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use the `NSTimeInterval` and calculate each component yourself. You can also do away with using `[NSDate date]`, and use [`timeIntervalSinceNow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceNow).
You can use integer division to discard the fractional part of each component.

```
// Use abs if you don't care about direction
NSTimeInterval duration = abs([self.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);

NSInteger days = ((NSInteger) duration) / (60 * 60 * 24);
NSInteger hours = (((NSInteger) duration) / (60 * 60)) - (days * 24);
NSInteger minutes = (((NSInteger) duration) / 60) - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
NSInteger seconds = ((NSInteger) round(duration)) % 60;
```

This should be quicker than dealing with `NSDateComponents`. It's not exactly what you're looking for but it does cover this :D

> without going through the fromDate/toDate rigamarole

Comment: @TimJones I'm Rich :P

Comment: Though I'll let you off if you put the correct name in your question update, haha :D

Comment: Sorry, Rich! The system inverted the order of the responses, and I didn't even look at the text when I scored the name for the update. It's fixed now, and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to skip the calculation step. I would recommend writing you a category on `NSDate` or `NSString` and implemented the desired conversion there.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolas! Turns out there was a way after all. Quick and dirty, but entirely adequate for the issue at hand. Please see update above.

Comment: hi tim, ah ok, but this one also takes the way over NSDate (that's what happens in `[self.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow]`), so that's not directly from `NSTimeInterval`. Anyhow, glad it works for you now! and btw, if you are using this code more often I would recommend to place it in a category so that you can easiliy access it whenever you need it :-)

Comment: @Nikolas-- Point well taken. In this particular case, though, as I pointed out in the question, the NSTimeIntervals have already been calculated elsewhere, so were already available as doubles.